# CSS Conditional Statements with hover

Tags: html, css, sass

This question might be simpler in conditional CSS.

I have five rows with some contents and based on some condition, I'm adding a class named **'previous'** to show different background color.

When I hover the previous class content, I'm getting transparent background which is not good.

I wanted to show the same background color (grey) even if it is hovered.

So, I tried the below code and tried to use **:has** condition in css, If it has previous class, change the hover color to grey. But it didn't worked.

My expectation is to have the same background color even if it is hovered.

Can someone help me on this as I need the solution only from **CSS/SCSS**. not from javascript.

```css
.previous {
  background-color: grey;
}
.row:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  :has(.previous) {
      background-color: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">Some Content 1</div>
<div class="row previous">Some Content 2</div>
<div class="row">Some Content 3</div>
<div class="row previous">Some Content 4</div>
<div class="row">Some Content 5</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just change the order of your selectors and add a hover to the previous class too:

```css
.row:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.previous,
.previous:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">Some Content 1</div>
<div class="row previous">Some Content 2</div>
<div class="row">Some Content 3</div>
<div class="row previous">Some Content 4</div>
<div class="row">Some Content 5</div>
```

Also, if you are wanting a row with the class previous, you just combine the selectors: `.row.previous`

`:has` is css4 and has very little support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Great Solution Pete :) Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using `:not` pseudo class to exclude rows with `previous` class from hover effect. Now `:hover` will run on every element that has a `.row` class but doesn't also have `.previous` class.

```css
.row {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.previous {
  background-color: grey;
}

.row:not(.previous):hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">Some Content 1</div>
<div class="row previous">Some Content 2</div>
<div class="row">Some Content 3</div>
<div class="row previous">Some Content 4</div>
<div class="row">Some Content 5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, we need to change the color to background: transparent to make it work :) Kudos for using :not condition :)

Comment: Red is just for the demo to better demonstrate the effect you can use any color in your code, the point here is the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure css solution.

You could set different styles for the hover when it has the previous class or not.

```css
.row:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.row.previous {
  background-color: grey;
}
.row.previous:hover {
  background-color: #595959; /*any color really*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row">Some Content 1</div>
<div class="row previous">Some Content 2</div>
<div class="row">Some Content 3</div>
<div class="row previous">Some Content 4</div>
<div class="row">Some Content 5</div>
```